# Not able to push a array of objects into an object during for loop and get desired model layout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects, that looks like this

```
var junkData = [
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1", ItemIndex: 0, ItemName: "Box 1" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1.0", ItemIndex: 1, ItemName: "Corrugate" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1.1", ItemIndex: 3, ItemName: "Sheet Metal" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "2", ItemIndex: 4, ItemName: "Box 2" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "3", ItemIndex: 5, ItemName: "Box 3" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "4", ItemIndex: 6, ItemName: "Box 4" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "4.0", ItemIndex: 7, ItemName: "Paper" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "4.1", ItemIndex: 8, ItemName: "Construction" }
];
```

and I am looping through them and placing the items into a data model

```
var DataModelObjects = {
    ItemInfo: function(model) {
        const itemModel = {
            ItemID: model.ItemID,
            RowNumber: model.RowNumber,
            ItemIndex: model.ItemIndex,
            ItemName: model.ItemName,
            Mods: model.Mods // List of this
        };
        return itemModel;
    }
}

const itemInfo = DataModelObjects.ItemInfo;
const itemModsInfo = DataModelObjects.ItemInfo;
const results = [];
for (let i = 0; i < junkData.length; i++) {
    if (!junkData[i].RowNumber.includes(".")) {
        itemInfo.ItemID = junkData[i].ItemID;
        itemInfo.RowNumber = junkData[i].RowNumber;
        itemInfo.ItemIndex = junkData[i].ItemIndex;
        itemInfo.ItemName = junkData[i].ItemName;

        results.push(DataModelObjects.ItemInfo(itemInfo));
    }
    else {
        itemModsInfo.ItemID = junkData[i].ItemID;
        itemModsInfo.RowNumber = junkData[i].RowNumber;
        itemModsInfo.ItemIndex = junkData[i].ItemIndex;
        itemModsInfo.ItemName = junkData[i].ItemName;

        results.push({ Mods: DataModelObjects.ItemInfo(itemModsInfo) });
    }
}
console.log(results);
```

and its coming out looking like this
[image: Screen Shot]

and what I am trying to have it come out like this

```
{
    ItemID:1, 
    RowNumber:"0", 
    ItemIndex:0, 
    ItemName: "Box 1", 
    Mods: [{
            ItemID:2, 
            RowNumber:"1.00", 
            ItemIndex:1, 
            ItemName: "Corrugate"
        }, 
        {
            ItemID:3, 
            RowNumber:"1.01", 
            ItemIndex:2, 
            ItemName: "Sheet Metal"
        }]
},
{
    ItemID:4, 
    RowNumber:"1", 
    ItemIndex:2, 
    ItemName: "Box 2", 
    Mods: [{
            ItemID:null, 
            RowNumber:"", 
            ItemIndex:null, 
            ItemName: ""
        }, 
        {
            ItemID:null, 
            RowNumber:"", 
            ItemIndex:null, 
            ItemName: ""
        }]
},
{
    ItemID:5, 
    RowNumber:"1", 
    ItemIndex:3, 
    ItemName: "Box 3", 
    Mods: [{
            ItemID:null, 
            RowNumber:"", 
            ItemIndex:null, 
            ItemName: ""
        }, 
        {
            ItemID:null, 
            RowNumber:"", 
            ItemIndex:null, 
            ItemName: ""
        }]
},
{
    ItemID:6, 
    RowNumber:"1", 
    ItemIndex:6, 
    ItemName: "Box 4", 
    Mods: [{
            ItemID:7, 
            RowNumber:"4.00", 
            ItemIndex:7, 
            ItemName: "Paper"
        }, 
        {
            ItemID:8, 
            RowNumber:"4.01", 
            ItemIndex:8, 
            ItemName: "Construction"
        }]
}
```

And I am having a problem doing this and could use some direction on this.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Thank you for everyone that has answered, all answers have worked. However, I still need to utilize the data models. The reason is that there is  other properties in the data that aren't needed and only data that is the same as the models need to be used.

Here is an updated datasource

```
var junkData = [
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1", ItemIndex: 0, ItemName: "Box 1", ItemPrice: 1.99, ItemQTY: 10 },
    { ItemID: 2, RowNumber: "1.0", ItemIndex: 1, ItemName: "Corrugate", ItemPrice: 1.99, ItemQTY: 1 },
    { ItemID: 3, RowNumber: "1.1", ItemIndex: 3, ItemName: "Sheet Metal", ItemPrice: 1.99, ItemQTY: 4 },
    { ItemID: 4, RowNumber: "2", ItemIndex: 4, ItemName: "Box 2", ItemPrice: 4.99, ItemQTY: 5 },
    { ItemID: 5, RowNumber: "3", ItemIndex: 5, ItemName: "Box 3", ItemPrice: 2.99, ItemQTY: 3 },
    { ItemID: 6, RowNumber: "4", ItemIndex: 6, ItemName: "Box 4", ItemPrice: 9.99, ItemQTY: 2 },
    { ItemID: 7, RowNumber: "4.0", ItemIndex: 7, ItemName: "Paper", ItemPrice: 11.99, ItemQTY: 2 },
    { ItemID: 8, RowNumber: "4.1", ItemIndex: 8, ItemName: "Construction", ItemPrice: 1.99, ItemQTY: 4 }
];
```

I have reworked a solution that was provided by @tarkh, but running into issues with the mods, here is the rework

```
var junkData = [
        { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1", ItemIndex: 0, ItemName: "Box 1", ItemPrice: 1.99, ItemQTY: 10 },
        { ItemID: 2, RowNumber: "1.0", ItemIndex: 1, ItemName: "Corrugate", ItemPrice: 1.99, ItemQTY: 1 },
        { ItemID: 3, RowNumber: "1.1", ItemIndex: 3, ItemName: "Sheet Metal", ItemPrice: 1.99, ItemQTY: 4 },
        { ItemID: 4, RowNumber: "2", ItemIndex: 4, ItemName: "Box 2", ItemPrice: 4.99, ItemQTY: 5 },
        { ItemID: 5, RowNumber: "3", ItemIndex: 5, ItemName: "Box 3", ItemPrice: 2.99, ItemQTY: 3 },
        { ItemID: 6, RowNumber: "4", ItemIndex: 6, ItemName: "Box 4", ItemPrice: 9.99, ItemQTY: 2 },
        { ItemID: 7, RowNumber: "4.0", ItemIndex: 7, ItemName: "Paper", ItemPrice: 11.99, ItemQTY: 2 },
        { ItemID: 8, RowNumber: "4.1", ItemIndex: 8, ItemName: "Construction", ItemPrice: 1.99, ItemQTY: 4 }
    ];

    var DataModelObjects = {
    ItemInfo: function (model) {
        const itemModel = {
            ItemID: model.ItemID,
            RowNumber: model.RowNumber,
            ItemIndex: model.ItemIndex,
            ItemName: model.ItemName,
            Mods: model.Mods, // List of this
        };
            return itemModel;
        }
    };

    
    const items = junkData;
    const itemInfo = DataModelObjects.ItemInfo;
    const itemModsInfo = DataModelObjects.ItemInfo;
    

    // Set new array
    const dataHolder = [];

    // Loop
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        // Item copy
        const item = { ...items[i] };
        // Try to split by .
        const isAttAccMod = item.RowNumber.split(".");
        // Check if . exist
        if (isAttAccMod[1]) {
            for (let i = 0; i < dataHolder.length; i++)
                if (dataHolder[i].RowNumber === isAttAccMod[0]) {
                    itemModsInfo.ItemID = junkData[i].ItemID;
                    itemModsInfo.RowNumber = junkData[i].RowNumber;
                    itemModsInfo.ItemIndex = junkData[i].ItemIndex;
                    itemModsInfo.ItemName = junkData[i].ItemName;

                    dataHolder[i].Mods.push(DataModelObjects.ItemInfo(itemModsInfo));
                }
        } else {
            // Extend item with Mods array
            itemModsInfo['Mods'] = [];

            itemInfo.ItemID = item.ItemID;
            itemInfo.RowNumber = item.RowNumber;
            itemInfo.ItemIndex = item.ItemIndex;
            itemInfo.ItemName = item.ItemName;
            // Push to new array
            dataHolder.push(DataModelObjects.ItemInfo(itemInfo));
        }
    }

    // Log
    console.log(dataHolder);
```

Right now this is returning
[image: Screenshot 2]

So its getting there, but not quite.

Comment: `DataModelObjects.ItemInfo` is a function, but you reference it like it's a property and try to add other properties to it.

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier, I see what you're getting at, and now I think what I need to do is where the row number includes a . then I should push that into an array then push that array into the Mods property. It was built this way because at times I get data back from the database and I push the data into this function and use the variable that I set it in, and at times this model gets sent to the database

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Check code below, read comments. This is the simplest and compact (if you remove comments) way of doing this using simple `for` loop

```js
var junkData = [
  { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1", ItemIndex: 0, ItemName: "Box 1" },
  { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1.0", ItemIndex: 1, ItemName: "Corrugate" },
  { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1.1", ItemIndex: 3, ItemName: "Sheet Metal" },
  { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "2", ItemIndex: 4, ItemName: "Box 2" },
  { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "3", ItemIndex: 5, ItemName: "Box 3" },
  { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "4", ItemIndex: 6, ItemName: "Box 4" },
  { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "4.0", ItemIndex: 7, ItemName: "Paper" },
  { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "4.1", ItemIndex: 8, ItemName: "Construction" }
];

// Set new array
const newJunkData = [];

// Loop
for(let i = 0; i < junkData.length; i++) {
  // Item copy
  const item = {...junkData[i]};
  // Try to split by .
  const dot = item.RowNumber.split(".");
  // Check if . exist
  if(dot[1]) {
    // Find proper row in new array and put data to it's Mod.
    // We'll find proper row by comparing digit before . with
    // RowNumber that should already exist in our new array.
    // So i.e 2.1 or 2.01 etc. will be pushed to Mods of 2
    for(let i = 0; i < newJunkData.length; i++) if(newJunkData[i].RowNumber === dot[0]) newJunkData[i].Mods.push(item);
  } else {
    // Extend item with Mods array
    item['Mods'] = [];
    // Push to new array
    newJunkData.push(item);
  }
}

// Log
console.log(newJunkData);
```

Comment: This works, but I need it to work with the data models, because the data being returned has more properties than whats in the data model.

Comment: I edited my question with a rework of your solution

Answer (score 1):

This was done in two function in order to check for the properties you are going to insert into the `Mods`

```js
var junkData = [
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1", ItemIndex: 0, ItemName: "Box 1" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1.0", ItemIndex: 1, ItemName: "Corrugate" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "1.1", ItemIndex: 3, ItemName: "Sheet Metal" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "2", ItemIndex: 4, ItemName: "Box 2" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "3", ItemIndex: 5, ItemName: "Box 3" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "4", ItemIndex: 6, ItemName: "Box 4" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "4.0", ItemIndex: 7, ItemName: "Paper" },
    { ItemID: 1, RowNumber: "4.1", ItemIndex: 8, ItemName: "Construction" },
];

var DataModelObjects = {
    ItemInfo: function (model) {
        const itemModel = {
            ItemID: model.ItemID,
            RowNumber: model.RowNumber,
            ItemIndex: model.ItemIndex,
            ItemName: model.ItemName,
            Mods: model.Mods, // List of this
        };
        return itemModel;
    },
};

const itemInfo = DataModelObjects.ItemInfo;
const itemModsInfo = DataModelObjects.ItemInfo;
var results = [];

newArray = (array) => {
    array.forEach((arr, i) => {
        if (!arr.RowNumber.includes(".")) {
            arr["Mods"] = [];
            results.push(arr);
        } else {
            setProperty(array, arr);
        }
    });
};

setProperty = (array, prop, index) => {
    array.forEach((arr) => {
        if (prop.RowNumber.substring(0, prop.RowNumber.indexOf(".")) === arr.RowNumber) {
            arr["Mods"].push(prop);
        }
    });
};
newArray(junkData);
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to make sure that your array of objects is in the order that you want the result in, and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a new array from the `junkData` array. The reduce function will be the most complex as it will determine the logic to add a item to the top level of the array or to add a item to an existing object in the `Mods` property.

```js
const sortJunkData = (a, b) => {
  if (a.RowNumber > b.RowNumber) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a.RowNumber < b.RowNumber) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
};

const reduceJunkData = (acc, cur) => {
  const { RowNumber } = cur;
  const splitRowNumber = RowNumber.split('.');
  if (splitRowNumber.length > 1) {
    const target = acc.find(item => item.RowNumber === splitRowNumber[0]);
    if (target !== null) {
      if (!Array.isArray(target.Mods)) {
        target.Mods = [];
      }
      target.Mods.push(cur);
    } else {
      acc.push(cur);
    }
  } else {
    acc.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
}

var junkData = [
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "1.0",
    ItemIndex: 1,
    ItemName: "Corrugate"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "1",
    ItemIndex: 0,
    ItemName: "Box 1"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "1.1",
    ItemIndex: 3,
    ItemName: "Sheet Metal"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "1.2",
    ItemIndex: 3,
    ItemName: "Sheet Metal"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "2",
    ItemIndex: 4,
    ItemName: "Box 2"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "3.1",
    ItemIndex: 5,
    ItemName: "Box 3"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "3",
    ItemIndex: 5,
    ItemName: "Box 3"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "3.2",
    ItemIndex: 5,
    ItemName: "Box 3"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "4",
    ItemIndex: 6,
    ItemName: "Box 4"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "4.0",
    ItemIndex: 7,
    ItemName: "Paper"
  },
  {
    ItemID: 1,
    RowNumber: "4.1",
    ItemIndex: 8,
    ItemName: "Construction"
  }
];

const formattedJunkData = Array.from(junkData)
  .sort(sortJunkData)
  .reduce(reduceJunkData, []);

console.log(formattedJunkData);
```

Comment: I'll check this out once back to my laptop. What I failed to mention is that when you see row 1, or 4, that the following 1.0, 1.01 is related to row number 1. I'll explain when I update my question with the missed information

Comment: I figured that was the logic of your output, so I took that into account.